# Is there a text box parameter type for Python Toolboxes?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, parameters, python-toolbox

The Calculate Field tool has a text box for code.

[image]

Is there a parameter type for Python Toolboxes for this type? There's `String` but it's just one row of text.

```
    in_str = arcpy.Parameter(
        name='test',
        displayName='Test',
        datatype='String',
        direction='Input',
        parameterType='Required')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that there is not. Only a subset of what is available using ArcObjects is exposed via ArcPy. Another input parameter that is on many system tool dialogs but not accessible to Python Toolbox and Python Script tools is the color picker.